# Make sure path in Go template always ends with slash

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates, sprig-template-functions

I am writing a Helm chart for a bunch of deployments. I am supplying a value which can be:

`my_value: "/opt/my-path"`or `my_value: "/opt/my-path/"`

Now I would want to make sure that there is always a single `/` at the end of the path.

How do I do this using `Go` templates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can trim the suffix `/` with `trimSuffix` function, docs here http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/strings.html, and to add `/` manually at the end. So regardless the original value you will always get a `/` at the end. 
example

values.yaml:

```
path_with_slash: "/my/path/"
path_without_slash: "/my/path"
```

inside a template file:

```
{{ $path_with_slash := trimSuffix "/" .Values.path_with_slash }}
{{ $path_without_slash := trimSuffix "/" .Values.path_without_slash }}
path_with_slash: "{{ $path_with_slash }}/"
path_without_slash: "{{ $path_without_slash }}/"
```

rendered file:

```
path_with_slash: "/my/path/"
path_without_slash: "/my/path/"
```

Comment: I ended up doing it in a single line but it works as expected. Thank you `mountPath: {{ .mountPath | default "/var/config/" | trimSuffix "/" }}/{{ base .file }}`